# how to setup Twilio

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, twilio

I'm trying to implement Twilio to my WP8 application so I can send messages, I have downloaded the API helper and I have tried implement the c# just to test if it works. I am only a beginner at programming and I don't really understand why it wont work.

```
class sendmessages
 {
    private static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
  string AccountSid = "......"; //My own details 
  string AuthToken = "......."; //My own details

var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var message = twilio.SendSmsMessage("From" "TO", "hello ");

Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing to do cause the Twilio Website is not very helpful, as the documentation is not very clear. I don't want anyone to do it for me, any tutorials that would help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Are you getting a specific error?

To start debugging this I'd suggest checking to make sure that the RestException property is null:

```
var message = twilio.SendSmsMessage("[YOUR_FROM_NUMBER]","[YOUR_TO_NUMBER]","[MESSAGE_BODY]");
if (message.RestException != null) {

    //An error happened calling the REST API
    Debug.Writeline(message.RestException.Message);

}
```

If RestException is null, I'd suggest checking the logs in the Twilio developer portal to see if Twilio reports sending a message.

If neither of those two things work, my next suggestion would be to use Fiddler to watch the actual HTTP request the library is making to the REST API and see what the result is.

Hope that helps.